# focus between an inputText and commandButton when multiple inputText and commandButton

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm using richfaces and jsf.

I've a form which look like that :

```
<h:form>

    <h:inputText id="id1" value="#{mybean.1}" />
    <h:commandButton id="button1" action="#{otherBean.goToPage1}">
        <f:ajax execute="id1" render="id1" />
    </h:commandButton>

    <h:inputText id="id2" value="#{mybean.2}" />
    <h:commandButton id="button2" action="#{otherBean.goToPage2}">
        <f:ajax execute="id2" render="id2" />
    </h:commandButton>        

    <h:inputText id="id3" value="#{mybean.3}" />
    <h:commandButton id="button3" action="#{otherBean.goToPage3}">
        <f:ajax execute="id3" render="id3" />
    </h:commandButton>

</h:form>
```

My problem is that when I'm writing something on the input "id3" and I press ENTER, the commandButton for "id1" is reading.
Or what I want is, when I press Enter in an input, the good commandButton is reading (input1 for button1, input2 for button2, ...)

For my project I have to use just one form.

Have anyone an idea ?

Comment: You have forgotten to close your `"id2"` commandButton component.

Comment: thanks, but the problem continues

Comment: Brake down your problem...First make sure there is NO default commandbutton (how to do that search stackoverflow). Then look for a Q/A in Stackoverflow that detects an enter-press in an input and make that 'click' the right button via javascript.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the first button on the form is the default button. I tried to include some javascript, but even after researching I can not find a solution that solves my problem

Comment: _"If I understood correctly, the first button on the form is the default button. "_ : correct

Answer (score 0):

I find what was missing :

```
<h:inputText id="id1" value="#{mybean.1}" 
             onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) { #{rich:element('button1')}.click();}"
             onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { #{rich:element('button1')}.click();}"/>
<h:commandButton id="button1" action="#{otherBean.goToPage1}">
    <f:ajax execute="id1" render="id1" />
</h:commandButton>
```

the two lines "**onkeyup**" and "**onkeydown**" have to be add on every inputText and **#{rich:element('button1')}** replace **document.getElementById('button1')**

For Internet Explorer I add : **onblur="#{rich:element('button1')}.click();"**

```
<h:inputText id="id1" value="#{mybean.1}" 
             onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) { #{rich:element('button1')}.click();}"
             onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { #{rich:element('button1')}.click();}"
             onblur="#{rich:element('button1')}.click();" />
```

It works on IE8 and IE11.

Comment: why both keyup and keydown?

Comment: keyup is the one which work, but without keydown, I have some little bug with my real code ... I don't know why

Comment: I juste realize that the code works fine in Firefox or Chrome but doesn't work on IE

Comment: I remember there being issues with key codes and maybe even the events. But you have to state what exactly happens in the other browsers... Add e.d. console.log statements

Comment: I've got nothing in the IE console but it still don't work